# Why Velocity templates are not recognized in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, velocity

I want to set up my existing Spring application with Spring Boot. I apply *spring-boot:run* command.

I did some changes in configrutions, so I can start the application, open login page, but the place where velocity template *login.vm* should be it shows only *login* text instead of the content of *login.vm*:

[image]

My ApplicationConfig:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:/applicationContext*.xml", "classpath:/static/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"my.package"})
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }

    };
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
RequestDumperFilter requestDumper() {
    return new RequestDumperFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean siteMeshFilter(){
    FilterRegistrationBean fitler = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    MySiteMeshFilter siteMeshFilter = new MySiteMeshFilter();
    fitler.setFilter(siteMeshFilter);
    return fitler;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilterChainRegistration() {
    DelegatingFilterProxy delegatingFilterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    delegatingFilterProxy.setTargetBeanName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(delegatingFilterProxy);
    registrationBean.setName(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public WebAppRootListener webAppRootListener() {
    return new WebAppRootListener();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/");
    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("load-on-startup","1");
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new DispatcherServlet();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}


@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    VelocityViewResolver resolver = new VelocityViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".vm");
    return resolver;
}
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public VelocityConfigurer velocityConfig() throws IOException {
    VelocityConfigurer velocityConfigurer = new VelocityConfigurer();
    velocityConfigurer.setResourceLoaderPath("/templates/velocity/");
    Properties properties =  new Properties();
    properties.put("output.encoding","UTF-8");
    properties.put("input.encoding","UTF-8");
    properties.put("file.resource.loader.path","/templates/velocity/");
    File file = new ClassPathResource("/templates/velocity/macroses.vm").getFile();
    properties.put("velocimacro.library",file);
    velocityConfigurer.setVelocityProperties(properties);
    return velocityConfigurer;
}
}
```

MySiteMeshFilter:

```
public class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
@Override
protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
    builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/default-decorator.jsp")
            .addDecoratorPath("/login.html", "/WEB-INF/decorators/login-decorator.jsp")
            .addDecoratorPaths("/admin/crowd/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/crowd-decorator.jsp"
                    ,"/WEB-INF/decorators/default-decorator.jsp")
            .addDecoratorPaths("/admin/project/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/project-decorator.jsp",
                    "/WEB-INF/decorators/default-decorator.jsp")
            .addDecoratorPaths("/admin/report/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/report-decorator.jsp"
                    , "/WEB-INF/decorators/default-decorator.jsp");
}
}
```

login-decorator.jsp has the following lines:

```
<h2><sitemesh:write property='title'/></h2>
<sitemesh:write property='body'/>
```

LoginController.java has:

```
@RequestMapping("/login.html")
public String login(params here) {
    //some checks
    return "login";
}
```

My pom.xml contains the follwoing dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
  <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Velocity templates are located in *src/main/resources/templates/velocity*.

Decorators are located in *src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/decorators*.

I do not have errors in logs.

So my question: Why my application show *login* text instead of *login.vm* velocity template? How to fix this?

**How I fixed the issue:**

1. I changed @RestController to @Controller
2. Added *VelocityAutoConfiguration* like described [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisi/11249866)
3. Deleted unnesesary configurations from ApplicationConfig - leave `siteMeshFilter()` method only.

Comment: Let me guess that `@RequestMapping` is in a `@RestController` annotated class.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes, but if I change RestController to Controller, I have error "Whitelabel Error Page. This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Comment: You have to use `@Controller` else it won't resolve to a view. The error you get is an indication of another issue. You are also trying very hard NOT to use Spring Boot... You configure everything yourself, why, Spring Boot auto configures all that for you already.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right. [`@RestController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) is `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`. `@ResponseBody` on a method that returns a string makes Spring to return that string as plain text in response.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I configured everything by myself because I tried to "migrate" my old project where are everything are configured. But yes, I removed my configurations and application works. Thanks.

Comment: @naXa, thank you too. Changing `@RestController` to `@Controller` has helped me.

Comment: If you already have a working configuration work with that instead of trying to add configuration. If the configuration you had worked just load that configuration into your Spring Boot application and make it work. Then start removing the parts that you explicitly configured and let Spring Boot manage that configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I will try, thanks.

Comment: @user3186861 Do not edit your question if you have found an answer by yourself. It may become harder for others who have the same problem to find your answer. Answers belong in answers, not in questions. So it's ok to answer your own question. Read this help topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and please edit your answer out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

**How I fixed the issue:**

1. I changed @RestController to @Controller
2. Added VelocityAutoConfiguration like described here
3. Deleted unnesesary configurations from ApplicationConfig - leave siteMeshFilter() method only.